# SOAP request. Convert string to byte array

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have Soap WS on Java.
Here is soap request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:his="SCC/Lis/HistoryFormatter">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <his:formatHistoryByteArray>
         <arg0>cid:anystring</arg0>
      </his:formatHistoryByteArray>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

FormatHistoryByteArray.class  has only one field

```
@XmlElement(name = "arg0", namespace = "", nillable = true)
private byte[] arg0;
```

Type in *.xsd

```
  <xs:complexType name="formatHistoryByteArray">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:base64Binary" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

WSDL and xsd is generated by JaxWS.
I cann't understand logic of convertion string in  node in request to byte[] in java-code. Help plz
*cid:* is the requared prefix or not?

**Edited:**
for example, if I have request

```
<arg0>abcdef</arg0>
```

in java code I get byte[] = {105, -73, 29}

How WebService get this byte array from string *abcdef*?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. If you're looking to convert string to byte[] then use `stringValue.getBytes()`

Comment: WebService automaticaly convert String to byte[], but this result is different with stringValue.getBytes() result.

Comment: No it doesn't. Your complexType defined for `formatHistoryByteArray` is a base64 encoded value, you'll have use either `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` or similar to decode the value back to byte[] or object.

Comment: @Bitmap Doesn't JAXB do that conversion automatically?

Comment: `xs:base64Binary` has been specified explicitly as your value type, therefore binding object will hold encoded bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.getBytes()` returns you the (ASCII, UTF8, ISO-8859-1 etc.) encoding of a given `String`. That's different from what Base 64 is. Base 64 is a way of displaying arbitrary bytes as printable characters. So there is no reason for them to be the same.

Have a look at section 2.1 of this tutorial on Base 64 and XML: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/02/26/binaryxml.html. The base64 bit looks like this:

```
<m:data xmlns:m='http://example.org/people' >
  <photo>/aWKKapGGyQ=</photo>
  <sound>sdcfo2JTiXE=</sound>
  <hash>Faa7vROi2VQ=</hash>
</m:data>
```

where `photo` etc. are base64 elements. `cid` prefix is not needed.

To address your question, `abcdef` is being interpreted by the web service unmarshaller as a base-64 encoded string as the three bytes you received.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Bitmap I've updated the answer as best I could, given how unclear the question is.

Answer (score 0):

The schema specifically declares the type as: "xs:base64Binary"  aka: BINARY.   If you expect the the information to be textual in nature, the type should likely be "xs:string" or similar.

Actually, the service should be rejecting the value of "cid:anystring" entirely.   That's not a valid value for a base64 encoded element.